# Change icon of cursor when mouse hover at button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game, in which I need to change the icon of the cursor, when the cursor points at a button, and retains back to normal condition when not pointing at button. So far I had done this, but nothing good, any suggestions where I am going wrong?
I am attaching this script at button...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cursor : MonoBehaviour {

  Vector2 mouse;
  int w =32;
  int h=32;
  public Texture2D cursor1;
  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    Cursor.visible = true;
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
    mouse = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y);
  }
  void OnMouseOver()
  {
    Cursor.SetCursor (cursor1, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
  }
  void OnMouseExit()
  {
    Cursor.SetCursor (null,Vector2.zero,CursorMode.Auto);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Event Trigger for UI system to change the icon for the system or any input based interactions(This is way easy to implement).

First Change your Mouse over and Mouse Exit functions to public.
Add event system to your buttons which you want cursor to change on hover by 
Add component-> Event Trigger -> Add New Event Type ->

> Here there are multiple events you can choose from but you need only on Pointer Enter and Pointer Exit

So select your **Pointer Enter** & **Pointer Exit**
-> Click ‘**+**’ sign -> Drag and drop your cursor script in the both places and select your respective function from scripts and execute your program.

[image]

Another way is to implement Event system functions in your cursor script and place it on button object but i think doing first method is clean and easy to implement. [Event Trigger Scripted Implementation 1](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html)

> Note: Your old mouse over will work on objects on 3D world which has colliders and not as UI so that is why your cursor script is not working for buttons as buttons are in UI space. Though you can make them work in UI also using 3D/2D colliders but you will have to go with raycasters which is a bit long method to implement. I would rather go with simple ones unless required

[Event Trigger Info](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-events-and-event-triggers)

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this link on Unity Doc:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.SetCursor.html

Did you configure the texture in the inspector like needed?

> The texture to use for the cursor or null to set the default cursor.
>   Note that a texture needs to be imported with "Read/Write enabled" in
>   the texture importer (or using the "Cursor" defaults), in order to be
>   used as a cursor.